# Plotting a constant in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two arrays where C is a constant

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

constants = var('C')
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [C, 2*C, 3*C, 4*C, 5*C]

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.grid(true)
plt.savefig("pru")
plt.close()
```

But when I try plot this with Matpotlib, give my this error:

```
TypeError: unable to simplify to float approximation
```

How I can plot this?

Comment: could you edit your code and include your `plot` statement?

Comment: `C` is a symbolic expression.  Matplotlib has no idea what `y` value `C` is supposed to correspond to.  What are you trying to get out?

Comment: @DSM is right.  Do you want something interactive? That is also [possible](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxzyMwrSS1KTC7h5UpJTVOI13C2NdW04uVSAIKcYgVbhWhDHSMdYx0THdNYmKgzSNhZK0chLb9IIUchMw8oBpUMAEoVJyeWAM2ML8jJL9GoyizQyCnWAWrS1IQoKc7IL9cI0EkvykzJycxLLbYNKSpN1QQAjUAmBw==&lang=sage).

Comment: The final idea is, with a function, make a plot similar to this https://tinyurl.com/kgt7sxe but where I = C, and I1 = C*cte where cte is calculated for each point

Answer (score 2):

If you use numpy arrays, multiplying an array by a constant is done element-wise, automatically:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

c = 2.0
x = np.arange(5)
y = c*x

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: My problem is, C is a constant but I don't know his value

Comment: How are you supposed to plot something if you don't know what it is? If C _is_ a constant however, you could simply change the label on the yaxis to reflect this - multiplying a function by a constant C only changes the scale on the yaxis, i.e. you'd be plotting in "units" of C.